# Cannot import css from node_modules

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript and web dev server to run my app... i start the app using the following:

```
tsc && concurrently -k -r \"tsc --watch\" \"wds --watch\"
```

In one of my `.ts` file, I import css from `node_modules` as follows:

```
import "gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css";
```

No error on running the app, but the page won't load and console error shows:

```
Failed to load module script.  
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css".  
String MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I tried adding the following in tsconfig.json but still same error:

```
...
plugins: [
    {"name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"},
    ...
]
```

Please advise.

Comment: Pretty sure you need a bundler to handle CSS in JS / TS. That plugin is just for editor support

Comment: I'm not bundling cause I'm creating a library project.  Can please advise how to go about this?

Comment: can you tell us what kind of library this is? is it a javascript library intended for web only? is it not specific to be used for certain frameworks (react, vue, etc.)? from my understanding, what you want is "when this library is imported to a js project, you want the CSS to be automatically inserted to the web page which imports this library", is that correct?

Comment: i'm creating a web component library using lit framework but i am not doing any minification or bundling cause i want the application that will use my library to do the bunding/minification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution already, need to import it as follows:

```
import gridstackStyles "gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" assert { type: 'css' };
```

Answer (score 0):

True, you can import CSS directly within a TypeScript file using `import assert { type: 'css' };`, as described in "[Using CSS Module Scripts to import stylesheets](https://web.dev/articles/css-module-scripts)" from [Dan Clark](https://github.com/dandclark).

But it does blur the lines between styling and scripting to some extent.
In traditional web development practices, keeping CSS (styling), JavaScript/TypeScript (behavior), and HTML (structure) separate is often recommended for maintainability and clarity.

Since you are developing a web component library, bundling CSS with your JavaScript or TypeScript might be acceptable, especially if each component's styling is tightly coupled with its functionality. That approach is common in component-based libraries and frameworks.

But you could also provide CSS as a *separate* file, which offers more flexibility to the users of your library: they can choose to override or extend the styles more easily without having to modify the component's internal logic.

You would essentially create a standalone CSS file that contains all the necessary styles for your library, well-organized and documented, making it easy for users of your library to understand how to utilize it.

For instance:

```css
/* gridstack-library-styles.css */
/* That is the main stylesheet for the GridStack Web Component Library */

/* Base styles for the GridStack components */
.gridstack-component {
    /* base styles here */
}

/* Specific component styles */
.gridstack-component-item {
    /* specific styles for component item */
}

/* Modifier classes for different states or variations */
.gridstack-component-item-active {
    /* styles for active state */
}

/* Responsive styles, if any */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .gridstack-component {
        /* responsive styles */
    }
}

/* other styles as needed */
```

Here, `.gridstack-component`, `.gridstack-component-item`, etc., are class names you would use in your Web Components. Consumers of your library would then include this CSS file in their project to get the desired styling.

For the consumer, the usage would be straightforward. They would include this CSS file in their HTML or import it in their JavaScript/TypeScript depending on their project setup.
For example, in a simple HTML scenario:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <!-- Importing the CSS file -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/gridstack-library-styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- Usage of your web components -->
      <gridstack-component></gridstack-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or, if they are using a build system like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/), they might import it directly into their JavaScript:

```js
import 'path/to/gridstack-library-styles.css';
// rest of their application code
```

The key is to provide clear instructions in your library's documentation on how to include and use this CSS file. That would help maintain the separation of concerns, keeps your TypeScript files clean from direct CSS imports, and allows the consumer of your library more flexibility in how they include and manage styles.